# Running R in an AWS Glue job

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Imagine you had a set of R scripts that form an ETL pipeline that you wanted to run as an AWS Glue job. AWS Glue supports Python and Scala.

Is it possible to call an R as a Python subprocess (or a bash script that wraps a set of R scripts) within an AWS Glue job running in a container with Python and R dependencies?

If so, please outline the steps required and key considerations.

Comment: Is there any reasons you need to run R scripts in Glue jobs, but not in AWS Batch or ECS?

Comment: No, there's not a particular reason to use Glue. Can you elaborate a bit on how you might go about this with AWS Batch or ECS?

Comment: Build a custom Docker image based on https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse, push the image to your repo in ECR, then create an ECS task or AWS Batch job.

Comment: Thanks @lsc. This seems to be the right answer. If you write it up, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Glue doesn't natively support running R scripts, you can consider the following as an alternative:

1. Customise your own Docker image
2. Push the image to ECR
3. Configure the compute resources and schedule using AWS Batch

Example folder structure

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── scripts
    └── rtest.R
```

Example Dockerfile based on https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.2.2
WORKDIR /scripts
COPY scripts/* /scripts
RUN chmod 755 ./*
# Install additional R libraries
```

Example commands to push the image to ECR

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com

docker build -t rdev .

docker tag rdev:latest aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/dev:latest

docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/dev:latest
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html

Then follow this guide to configure an ECS cluster on Fargate, create and execute a job: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/getting-started-fargate.html

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible**

While possible to run custom code in Glue, as it is based on Spark only Scala and Python are supported. Regarding the question if Python subprocess, it seems not to be an option as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-custom-created.html):

`Only pure Python libraries can be used. Libraries that rely on C extensions, such as the pandas Python Data Analysis Library, are not yet supported.`

As @Isc commented, I would recommend using Docker with ECS to run batch ETL jobs using R.